Delete everything outside of bounding boxes detectron2
I have trained a detectron2 model with one class. Now I want to set everything that is not inside of a bbox to the color white and keep the rest as it is. There can be multiple bboxes on one picture and they can overlay.
I read the docs of detectron2 as well as cv2 but I was not able to find a solution to my problem.
This is my code for the predictions:
from detectron2 import model_zoo
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.engine import DefaultPredictor
import cv2

cfg = get_cfg()
cfg.merge_from_file(model_zoo.get_config_file('COCO-Detection/tmp'))
cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS = 'tmp'

predictor = DefaultPredictor(cfg)

img = cv2.imread('tmp')

out = predictor(img)


image processing task. build a "mask" (bool array). give it a try. if it works, you can answer your own question. if it doesn't, show what you tried and how it failed.

When visualizing your image, just add the following:
instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW 

Here is my full visualization block, in case it helps:
output_dir = "output_images"
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

for i, d in enumerate(random.sample(dataset_dicts, 5)):    
    im = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
    outputs = mask_rcnn_predictor(im)
    v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
                   metadata=val_metadata, 
                   scale=1.5, 
                   instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW   # remove the colors of unsegmented pixels
    )
    v = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
    cv2.imshow("Window",v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])

    # Save the image
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(output_dir, f'image_{i}.jpg'), v.get_image()[:, :, ::-1])

    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == 27:  # if ESC is pressed, exit loop
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break

